# For WinRar, how long should a password be to make up for a lack of complexity?

Tags: keys, passwords

Assuming that the best alternative to complexity is length, how long do you recommend a password or phrase to be when using WinRar?

Note that I'm aware that it's not always that simple, but I would like to get this right.

Comment: **(1)** WinRar uses PBKDF2 internally to strengthen weak passwords. **(2)** There’s [*a related, usefull answer at Security.SE*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33248/26145) by @CodesInChaos which might come handy.

Comment: This depends at lot on version (public decryption code keeps trace of 5 variants), and in latest version may depend significantly on the KDF count as documented [there](https://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm), which apparently allows $2^{15}$ to $2^{24}$ rounds of password derivation.

Comment: thanks. i appreciate both of your responses. but what password length do you recommend for lack of complexity? thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> how long do you recommend a password or phrase to be when using
>   WinRar?

This very much depends on how you choose your passwords. The "right" answer can be anything from 11 characters to 200 characters.

So assuming [fgrieu's research](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/55097/for-winrar-how-long-should-a-password-be-to-make-up-for-a-lack-of-complexity#comment121871_55097) is correct (it usually is), the PBKDF uses at least $2^{15}$ rounds of hashing, giving us effectively 15 bits of security "for free". Now with the target being 100-bit security (which is reasonably secure for most intents and purposes), this leaves 85-bits to go. Now assuming you use the full ASCII-Range and good cryptographic randomness, this is about 11 bytes, or 11 characters. However assuming humans being humans, you will get much less randomness from short passwords. A conservative estimate would be **40 characters** (with a bit more than 2 bits of entropy per character) and a more aggressive estimate would be **16 characters** (assuming nearly fully random pick from upper- and lower-case latin letters).

Comment: My "research" is little more than looking at the [public doc](https://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm), and [public decryption source](https://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.5.8.tar.gz); finding `#define CRYPT5_KDF_LG2_COUNT     15 // LOG2 of PDKDF2 iteration count.` and `#define CRYPT5_KDF_LG2_COUNT_MAX 24 // LOG2 of maximum accepted iteration count.`; checking that the later is actually enforced as documented (assuming at-least-32-bit int) , and hypothesizing the former is the default (or is it minimum) for encryption.

Comment: thanks for your response. i'm gonna add 10 more to that 40 to make it 50 characters. - random words with CAPS on some of them, mixed in with numbers.

Comment: btw does that seem like a decent password? i know that nothing will beat a truly random password but it has to be somewhat decent right? lol if it's not decent, i'll just chose a semi-random password. - half generated, half chosen.

Comment: @john `… half chosen.` – Humans are pretty bad at generating cryptographically secure passwords. Why not completely generated your password using a CSPRNG? Every operating system has one.

Comment: because i need to be able to remember the pass without having it written anywhere. - even if it's encrypted using something like keepass, i'd still prefer to keep it in my memory.also, i was told a while ago that even if a password contains words, it still doesn't necessarily mean it can be cracked. as long as it's NOT grammatically correct. and as long as it contains special characters, caps and numbers; is there ANY truth to this? or is the person who said this incompetent? thank you all 4 your replies.

Comment: also, a month or two ago i was using a randomly generated password of 55 characters for some files. but i had a computer error and lost that data. and the files i backed up with that password, i can no longer access because on that computer was where i hid that random 55 character password which contained no words (that i can't remember).